# Pandas Using an If Statement to go row by row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I wasn't sure if that was the best title for this if someone else has a better idea for a title, I'm up for suggestions.

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df2

             A     section
0      <fruit>
1        apple
2       orange
3         pear
4   watermelon
5     </fruit>
6  <furniture>
7        chair
8         sofa
9        table
10        desk
11 </furniture>
```

What I want is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
             A     section
0      <fruit>       fruit
1        apple       fruit
2       orange       fruit
3         pear       fruit
4   watermelon       fruit
5     </fruit>       fruit
6  <furniture>   furniture
7        chair   furniture
8         sofa   furniture
9        table   furniture
10        desk   furniture
11 </furniture>  furniture
```

Is there a way to do this? I thought about using an if statement to go row by row, but I had problems with boolean logic when I did this.

Edit #1:

This solution, posted below, solves my problem.

Solution:

```
df['section']=pd.Series(np.where(df.A.str.contains('<'),df.A.str.replace('<|>|/',''),np.nan)).ffill()
```

What if I have data that looks like this? I would want the same result.

```
                                       A          section
0                                 <fruit>
1                <fruit_1>apple</fruit_1>
2               <fruit_2>orange</fruit_2>
3                 <fruit_3>pear</fruit_3>
4           <fruit_4>watermelon</fruit_4>
5                                </fruit>
6                             <furniture>
7        <furniture_1>chair</furniture_1>
8         <furniture_2>sofa</furniture_2>
9        <furniture_3>table</furniture_3>
10        <furniture_4>desk</furniture_4>
11                           </furniture>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC using `contains` find the row, and `np.where` assign the value , then using `ffill` fill the `np.nan`

```
df['section']=pd.Series(np.where(df.A.str.contains('<'),df.A.str.replace('<|>|/',''),np.nan)).ffill()
df
Out[1003]: 
               A    section
0        <fruit>      fruit
1          apple      fruit
2         orange      fruit
3           pear      fruit
4     watermelon      fruit
5       </fruit>      fruit
6    <furniture>  furniture
7          chair  furniture
8           sofa  furniture
9          table  furniture
10          desk  furniture
11  </furniture>  furniture
```

If you want to be more precise/specific/stricter, you can also check the start and end of the string using the `startswith` and `endswith`.

```
df1['Section'] = pd.Series(np.where(df1.A.str.startswith('<') & df1.A.str.endswith('>'), df1.A.str.replace('<|>|/',''), np.nan)).ffill()
```

Comment: what do you mean by "IIUC" ? What does that stand for?

Comment: Thanks wen!, I am playing around with this now, will update shortly

Comment: I made a small edit to my post for a different dataset, if you don't mind taking a look at that :) If not, no big deal :)

Comment: @LunchBox using this to change your original df , then using the same method `df.A=df.A.str.extract('>(.*?)<',expand=True)[0].fillna(df.A)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd choose to be explicit

```
import re

def parse_funky_xml(s):
  tag = None
  for x in s:
    if tag is None:
      match = re.match('<([^/]+)>', x)
      if match:
        tag = match.groups()[0]
      yield tag
    else:
      match = re.match(f'</{tag}>', x)
      yield tag
      if match:
        tag = None

df.assign(section=[*parse_funky_xml(df.A)])

               A    section
0        <fruit>      fruit
1          apple      fruit
2         orange      fruit
3           pear      fruit
4     watermelon      fruit
5       </fruit>      fruit
6    <furniture>  furniture
7          chair  furniture
8           sofa  furniture
9          table  furniture
10          desk  furniture
11  </furniture>  furniture
```